Prove: Let α be a proposition containing only Boolean connectives ∧,∨. Then any assignment satisfying α must also satisfy f(α)
The question:
Let f be a mapping that takes as input a Boolean proposition (no quantifiers) and outputs the same proposition but with all ∧ symbols replaced by ∨.
For example: $$ f(x_1 ∧ (x_2 → ¬x_5) = (x_1 ∨ (x_2 → ¬x_5) $$
Prove: Let α be a proposition containing only Boolean connectives ∧,∨.
Then any assignment satisfying α must also satisfy f(α).
I don't understand why this statement is true. I thought about a counter-example of α = β ∨ ¬β  is a Tautology. Hence every assignment satisfies α, but f(α) = β ∧ ¬β  is a Contradiction hence there is no assignment that satisfies f(α). what I'm missing here, and what is wrong with my thinking?

See Duality Principle in Boolean Algebra. You are right: the statement holds IF the formula is neither a tautology nor a contradiction.

@NaïmFavier correct, but vice versa α = β ∨ ¬β , it's still happening and contradict the claim, I will edit it, and I assume it's still problematic.

In short, the statement of the question is false, but it looks vaguely like something else that is true.

I don’t see how $f(\beta \lor \neg  \beta)=(\beta \land \neg \beta)$ given what you said.

@PW_246 "Let f be a mapping that takes as input a Boolean proposition (no quantifiers) and outputs the same proposition but with all ∧ symbols replaced by ∨ " look at the example of the function or explain what I'm missing.

Does $\beta \lor \neg \beta$ contain any conjunctions?

Oh, I thought $f$ was mapping $\lor$ to $\land$. My bad.

@PW_246 Not necessarily, I just thought about it as a counterexample, the full explanation might be done with Structural induction

Your counterexample is not a counterexample, because $f(\alpha) = \beta \lor \neg \beta$, not $\beta \land \neg \beta$.

@User33975329257439645 Yes, you can prove it by structural induction, but since there is the additional assumption that $\alpha$ contains only $\lor, \land$, you can also argue that since $(A \land B) \models (A \lor B)$, $f(\alpha)$ follows from $\alpha$, since both are strictly positive and $\land$ is stronger than $\lor$.

"containing only Boolean connectives $\wedge, \vee$": so in particular, does not contain Boolean connective $\lnot$.

@PW_246 correct, I can divide to cases.

@GEdgar or I'm missing something , but I think your statement is not possible since ¬(¬α))=α , can you explain more about this claim?

These are different expressions denoting the same Boolean function. One expression contains two $\neg$ connectives, the other none. $f$ acts on expressions.

For example ... $\alpha \wedge (\beta\vee \gamma) \mapsto \alpha \vee (\beta\vee \gamma)$.  Any assignment making $\alpha \wedge (\beta\vee \gamma)$ true also makes $\alpha \vee (\beta\vee \gamma)$ true.

This claim is not true without some assumption (such as the stated assumption that the only connectives in $\alpha$ are $\land$ and $\lor$). E.g., take $\alpha \equiv  \lnot (x \land  \lnot x)$. Then $\alpha$ is true under any assigment. But $f(\alpha) \equiv \lnot (x \lor \lnot x)$, which is false under any assignment.

The comparative concepts of being weaker and stronger (and their kin weak, weaken, etc.) are quite useful in logic. I shall describe the core idea; a formal argument can be organised accordingly:
These terms are used to describe the logical relationships between various logical notions (e.g., operators, formulas, systems) based on the amount of information they contain or the extent of their implications (e.g., theorems provable in a system).
So, a formula $\phi$ is said to be stronger than a formula $\psi$ if $\phi$ implies $\psi$, $\phi\rightarrow\psi$, but the converse does not necessarily hold. A formula $\phi$ is said to be weaker than a formula $\psi$ if $\phi$ if $\phi$ holds if $\psi$ does.
The idea can be illustrated with a plain example in natural language:
Let $\phi$ be the statement 'Socrates is walking swiftly' and $\psi$ be 'Socrates is walking'.
$\phi$ is stronger than $\psi$ since if it is the case that Socrates is walking swiftly, certainly, Socrates is walking. However, if it is the case that Socrates is walking slowly, then $\psi$ keeps to hold, but not $\phi$. In symbols, $\phi\rightarrow\psi$, but $\psi\not\rightarrow\phi$.
If $\phi$ and $\psi$ are logically equivalent, then neither is strictly weaker or stronger than the other.
The comparison of strength can be said to be analogous to subset, set, superset relations in set theory. A stronger statement is more informative or restrictive (has more specific or additional information), while a weaker statement is more general or permissive.
Hence, disjunction is a weaker connective than conjunction in propositional calculus:
$$(p\wedge q)\rightarrow(p\vee q)$$
but
$$(p\vee q)\not\rightarrow(p\wedge q)$$
Therefore, if a formula is true with $\wedge$, it can be said to be a fortiori true with $\wedge$s replaced with $\vee$s.
